# Incorrect value in text output - list.files

Tags: r, knitr

I'm starting to use KnitR for dynamic reporting. I've written a chunk to get the number of files in a specific directory ...

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
 correct_gtfiles <- list.files("data/")
 nr_corrGT <- length(correct_gtfiles)
```
````

... and I want to use this in the following text section:

```
 We have `r nr_corrGT` files.
```

However, when I knit the PDF, it outputs "... 0 files" instead of "114 files".
When I copy the two lines of the chunk in the RStudio console, I get the correct number:

```
> nr_corrGT
[1] 114
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because working directory is not the same for knitr and console. Try below:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
 correct_gtfiles <- list.files("data/")
 nr_corrGT <- length(correct_gtfiles)
```
We have `r nr_corrGT` files.
Current working directory is: `r getwd()`
````

We need to set working directory - `setwd()` or supply full path to `list.files`.